# Why am I only being returned 3 images instead of the correct amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently, trying to National Library of Australia's API to find pictures on a specific search term. [Trove API](http://help.nla.gov.au/trove/building-with-trove/api-technical-guide#anchor-1) I have the following functions which should send a query from an input form to the api and receive images back, however I am not receiving the majority of the images. In a particular example, if is search for 'sydney' I am only receiving 3 images back when there is in fact way more. For instance, [this is the json](http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=5d288qp21m735ekv&l-availability=y%2Ff&encoding=json&zone=picture&sortby=relevance&n=100&q=sydney&callback=), that is returned.
 I know that you will not be familiar with this api, but in my code below, is there anything that you can see, that would be causing it not to return all the images? I have changed a few things around to try and find the problem as well as put a few `console.log` statements but it is still not being kind to me.

```
var availableImages = { 
                "nla": {
                    "numImages":0,
                    "url_pattern":"nla.gov.au",
                    "images":[]
                },
            };

var url_patterns = ["nla.gov.au"];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#searchTrove").submit();

    $("form#searchTrove").submit(function() {

        resetImageData();

        //get input values
        var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val().trim();
        searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/ /g,"%20");
        var sortBy = $("#sortBy").val();

        //create searh query
        var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=" 
        + apiKey + "&l-availability=y%2Ff&encoding=json&zone=picture" 
        + "&sortby=relevance&n=100&q=" + searchTerm + "&callback=?";

        //print JSON object
        console.log(url);

        //get the JSON information we need to display the images
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $('#output').empty();

            $.each(data.response.zone[0].records.work, processImages);

            //console.log(data);

            printImages();
        });

    });

});

function processImages(index, troveItem){
    console.log("av"+ availableImages);

        for(var i in availableImages){
    //console.log(availableImages[i].url_pattern)
            if(troveItem.identifier[0].value.indexOf(availableImages[i].url_pattern) >= 0){
                console.log("Trove URL "+troveItem.identifier[0].value+"  Pattern: "+availableImages[i]["url_pattern"]);

                availableImages[i].numImages++;
                availableImages.totalimages++;
                availableImages[i]["images"].push(troveItem.identifier[0].value);
            }
        }
}

function printImages(){
                $("#output").append("<h3>Image Search Results</h3>");
                for(var i in availableImages){
                    if(availableImages[i]["url_pattern"]=="nla.gov.au" && availableImages[i]["numImages"]>0){
                        printNLAImages();
                        console.log(availableImages);
                    }
                }
            }


function printNLAImages(){
    $("#output").append("<h3>National Library of Australia</h3><p>"
            +availableImages["nla"]["numImages"]+" images found from <a href='http://"
            +availableImages["nla"]["url_pattern"]+"'>"
            +availableImages["nla"]["url_pattern"]+"</a></p>");

    for (var i in availableImages["nla"]["images"]){
        $("#output").append("<img src='"+availableImages["nla"]["images"][i]+"-v'>");
    }
    console.log(availableImages);
}

function resetImageData(){
availableImages.totalimages = 0;
for (var i in availableImages){
    availableImages[i].numImages = 0;
    availableImages[i]["images"] = [];
}
console.log(availableImages); //displaying hee
}
```

Comment: You're only using the images whose identifier contains `nla.gov.au`

Comment: so in the `printNLAImages` function should I remove all the ["nla"]?

Comment: When you `submit` the page it reloads everything. Better `return false;` after `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: I think the problem is in `processImage`. But I haven't really examined all the code, so I'm not sure of all that it's doing.

Comment: I would also not use `resetImageData()` every time upon submission.

Comment: @PHPglue thanks I have changed that. @Barmar `processImage` was a function that in the example I am trying to follow, dealt with a flickr element as well, but I have removed all of that.

Comment: `data.response.zone[0].records.work` (inside `$.each(data.response.zone[0].records.work, processImages);`) would have to be an Object or an Array which must contain an `identifier` property, which is an Array with Element `0` being an Object which has a `value` property. If that is not true then you do have an issue inside `processImages`.